# conditional class for html using pure handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js

I'm using handlebars to render code in server side (no angular/ember)

Can I still somehow have something like:
`<p dir="auto" {{#if isRTL: class=align-right}}>{{{content}}}</p>`

I want to have a CSS class only if a bolean is true
Something similar to ember's bind-attr...

Without it the code is a mess:

```
{{#if isRTL}}
    <p dir="auto" class="align-right>{{{content}}}</p>
{{else}}
    <p dir="auto">{{{content}}}</p>
{{#if}}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is not necessary to wrap around entire HTML elements. You can just wrap the `class` with the `if` clause.

```
<p dir="auto" {{#if isRTL}}class="align-right"{{/if}}>{{{content}}}</p>
```

This will render the `class="align-right"` attribute only if `isRTL` is truthy.

Also, as **Handlebars** is an extension of **Mustache** you could use:

```
<p dir="auto" {{#isRTL}}class="align-right"{{/isRTL}}>{{{content}}}</p>
```

Comment: Thanks! I also verified that the if statement inside an attribute works e.g.: <li class="answer {{#if isCorrect}}correct{{/if}}"

Comment: What version is that working? I'm getting error 
> Error: Parse error on line 2:
> ... <p dir="auto" {{#if="" isrtl}}class="al
> Expecting 'CLOSE_RAW_BLOCK', 'CLOSE', 'CLOSE_UNESCAPED', 'OPEN_SEXPR', 'CLOSE_SEXPR', 'ID', 'OPEN_BLOCK_PARAMS', 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'BOOLEAN', 'UNDEFINED', 'NULL', 'DATA', 'SEP', got 'EQUALS'

Answer (score 4):

With a helper i achieved clean. But in my case condition was two variables truthiness.

```
//js
Handlebars.registerHelper('ternary', function(cond, v1, v2) {
   return cond ? v1 : v2;
});
```

```
//html
<p dir="auto" class="some-other-class {{ternary isRTL 'align-right' 'align-left'}}">{{{content}}}</p>
```

Comment: I voted this up but actually I couldn't get it to work for me.

Answer (score 2):

I registered a helper to do this, to keep things cleaner, and in case there were more classes to add.

```
/**
 * Prints an objects key if the value is true.
 * example: {printed:true, pleaseprint:'hello', notprinted:false, noprint:undefined}
 */
handlebars.registerHelper("printif", function(object){
    // stringToPrint:boolean
    var out = [];
    for (var string in object) {
        var value = object[string];
        if (false===value || null===value || undefined===value) {
            continue;
        }
        out.push(string);
    }
    return out.join(' ');
});
```

And the template:

```
<div class="module {{printif moduleVars}}">
```

The variable:

```
var moduleVars = {"align-right":isRTL}
```

So if isRTL is true, it will output the string:

```
<div class="module align-right">
```